# Can't decrypt data flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption

I want to add auto sign in functions to my app. Also it should include encrypt/decrypt function.

My code is below:

this is where I get the parameters and encrypt them. I updated it as below

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

class EncryptData {
static Encrypted? encrypted;
static var decrypted;
static final iv = IV.fromLength(16);


static encryptAES(String plainText, String userKey) {
print(plainText);
final key = Key.fromUtf8(userKey);
// final iv = IV.fromLength(16);
final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));
encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
print(encrypted!.base64);
return encrypted;
 }

 static decryptAES(String encrypted, String userKey, String ivBase64) {
 final key = Key.fromUtf8(userKey);
 final iv = IV.fromBase64(ivBase64); //creating iv from the ivBase64 string
final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));
decrypted = encrypter.decrypt64(encrypted, iv: iv);
return decrypted.toString();
 }
}
```

I tried to add iv in storage:

```
 final storage =  FlutterSecureStorage();
                    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                     final userId = _auth.currentUser!.uid;
                     final newDateString = "1kr95ye3mcfgjt124p-54";  
                    String subUserId = userId.substring(0, 11);  
                    String key = subUserId + newDateString;
                    final String ivToBase64 = EncryptData.iv.base64 //store this in local storage
                    final String ivFromBase64 = IV.fromBase64(ivToBase64).base64;
                    var encryptMail;
                    var encryotPassword;
                    var encryptMailD;
                    var encryotPasswordD;
                    print("ANAHTAR: "+ key);
                    encryptMail = EncryptData.encryptAES(email.toString(), key);
                    encryotPassword = EncryptData.encryptAES(sifre.toString(), key); 
                    encryptMailD = EncryptData.decryptAES(encryptMail.base64, key,ivFromBase64);
                    encryotPasswordD = EncryptData.decryptAES(encryotPassword.base64, key,ivFromBase64);
                    print("DENEME : " + email);
                    print("DENEME : " + sifre);
                    print("DENEME2 : " + encryptMail.base64);
                    print("DENEME2 : " + encryotPassword.base64);
                    print("DENEME3 : " + encryptMailD.toString());
                    print("DENEME3 : " + encryotPasswordD.toString());
                    await storage.write(key: 'mail2', value: encryptMail!.base64);
                    await storage.write(key: 'password2', value: encryotPassword!.base64);
                    await storage.write(key: 'loginState2', value: true.toString());
                    await storage.write(key: "ilkOturum", value: "false");
                    await storage.write(key: "iv2", value: ivToBase64);
                    pref.setString('mail', encryptMail.base64);
                    pref.setString('password', encryotPassword.base64);
                    pref.setString('iv', ivToBase64);
                    pref.setBool('loginState', true);
                    print("bilgiler kayıt edildi");
```

and then decrypt :

```
var mail = await storage.read(key: 'mail2');
var password = await storage.read(key: 'password2');
var iv = await storage.read(key: 'iv2');

          if (mail != null && password != null) {
  var encryptMailD = EncryptData.decryptAES(mail, key, iv.toString());
  var encryotPasswordD = EncryptData.decryptAES(password, key, iv.toString());
```

Now it is working! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the **encryptAES** method and **decryptAES** the initialization vector (IV) is being generated independently, leading to an "Invalid or corrupted pad lock" error during decryption. When decrypting the "iv" should same which is used for encrypting the string.

Furthermore, it's important to note that when using IV.fromLength(16), it internally relies on Random.secure(), resulting in a different IV each time. To maintain consistency, consider storing and utilizing the same IV for both encryption and decryption, thereby preventing decryption errors.

```
class EncryptData {
static Encrypted? encrypted;
static var decrypted;

static final iv = IV.fromLength(16);

static encryptAES(String plainText, String userKey) {
print(plainText);
final key = Key.fromUtf8(userKey);
// final iv = IV.fromLength(16);
final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));
encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
print(encrypted!.base64);
return encrypted;
 }

 static decryptAES(String encrypted, String userKey, String 
    ivBase64) {
 final key = Key.fromUtf8(userKey);
 final iv = IV.fromBase64(ivBase64); //creating iv from the ivBase64 string
final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));
decrypted = encrypter.decrypt64(encrypted, iv: iv);
return decrypted.toString();
 }
}
```

---

```
final String ivToBase64 = iv.base64; //store this in local storage

final String ivFromBase64 = IV.fromBase64(ivToBase64);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I copied your code and tried but same error is continue. What should I do?

Comment: Can you update your code? it should be working

Comment: I updated but still I got this error :(

Comment: Can you update the code in your question here? With the error

Comment: I added. Error is same as before. I added debug result. I don't know if they should have the same length but email encrypt data longer than password encrypt. Is it can be the problem?

Comment: please make sure that the "userKey" is same for both methods.

Comment: Try to decrypt the strings just after you encrypt them if it's working then the problem is with your "key" you are passing in "AuthService().signInOto()".

Comment: I tried and added screenshots the question. Could you please check it?

Comment: From the screenshot : add ".base64" after "encryptMail" like: EncryptData.decryptAES(encryptMail.base64, key); and do the same with password and try to run it.

Comment: Thanks a million. I added ".base64" and I saw the data as decrypted. So as you said there is no problem with the key. I added AuthService().signInOto() function details to the question. Could you check it? Thanks a million for your help again. You are the best!

Comment: You can add print statements to check. if the "key" inside "AuthService().signInOto(EncryptData.decryptAES(mail, key),
        EncryptData.decryptAES(password, key), context);" is same as the key used in encryption or not.

Comment: I tried it but the keys are the same. What should we do? Everything seems ok but same error is continue

Comment: Try to print the "encryptMail" and "encryptPassword" and then print the email and password before decryption . They should be same.

Comment: Yes they are same

Comment: are you getting the first error again ? or the error in the third screenshot?

Comment: This error: Exception has occurred.
ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Invalid or corrupted pad block)

Comment: Now you are able to encrypt and decrypt the string so, it can be also done correctly from anywhere like AuthService(). The problem is not in the working of encrypt and decrypt process. So, Try to debug your code as much as possible

Comment: Could you please check code I added? I changed some codes in AuthServise. It is same with working code. Parameter is readed by storage. Is this should be problem?

Comment: In your auth service code are you able to read the print statements?

Comment: I mean storage read like that: storage.read(key: 'mail2'). Same code is working another page but when I get data from storage there is an error

Comment: yeah, it's correct but are you getting the values from storage.read(key: "mail2) ?

Comment: yes. first I encrypt data and save it to storage then try to decrypt to auto sign

Comment: I am asking that. when you are trying to get the values from the storage  are you able to get them or they are null? can you add print statement in AuthService(after this:     var mail = await storage.read(key: 'mail2'); to check if the mail is not null

Comment: Yes I checked. It is not null. It’s include encrypt data like working page. But I can’t decrypt it rivetingly.

Comment: update your auth service code in question with print statements where you read the "mail2" and "password2"

Comment: Top of the question : await storage.write(key: 'mail2', value: encryptMail!.base64);
                         await storage.write(key: 'password2', value: encryptPassword!.base64);

Comment: I reliazed that iv is changing when I restart the app so it can't decrypt the data. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Store the iv.base64 into local storage and get the value from local storage and pass the string into decryptAE() and create IV.fromBase64()

Comment: THANKS A MILLION. IT IS WORKING RIGHT NOW !!!! YOU ARE THE BEST